# Printing out a 2D array from input

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function to print a 2D array based off user input.

```
void inputSequence (char boardgame2 [26][26], int size) {

bool finished = false;
char color, row, col;

printf("\nEnter board configuration:\n");

while (!finished)
{
    scanf(" %c%c%c", &color, &row, &col);
      if (color == '!' && row == '!' && col == '!')
        finished = true;
}

printf("  ");
for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) 
    printf("%c", 'a'+col);

for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) 
{
    printf("\n%c", 'a'+row);
    printf(" ");

    for (int colU = 0; colU < size; colU++)
    {
        boardgame2 [row][colU]= 'U';
        boardgame2 [size/2][size/2]= 'W';
        boardgame2 [size/2-1][size/2-1]= 'W';
        boardgame2 [size/2-1][size/2] = 'B';
        boardgame2 [size/2][size/2-1] = 'B';
        boardgame2 [0][0] = color;

        printf("%c", boardgame2[row][colU]);
    }
}
}
```

The only problem is that the statement `boardgame2 [0][0] = color` prints out the last thing I entered, which is ! but I want it to be something the user inputs. The !!! should typed by user once they are done configuring the board.

Board configuration occurs by typing 3 letters, e.g Bab. where 1st letter represents the letter to be changed, a - row label, and b - column label.

So if the user types:

```
Bab

!!!
```

The configured will print out ! at the position (a,b) instead of B. How do I fix this?

Comment: The general structure of the program is wrong. It is 1) user input, 2) a combination of printing and initializing the array. It should be 1) initialize the array, 2) user input, 3) print the array.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying. The loop `while (!finished){...}` will repeat until you have entered `!!!` and then you don't change `color` before it's used in `boardgame2 [0][0] = color;` when it is still a `!`.

Comment: can you please explain, what you really want to do?